# Flow Type: HOC with cloneElement

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to create a higher order component, Hoc, that gives its children some extra props through React.cloneElement. I have not been able to get flowtype to know that the extra props were in fact passed down.

Below is my failed attempt, which throws the error foo type cannot be found on object literal. I would like to know what I can do to fix this.

```
type Props = {
  foo: string,
  bar: string,
};

type DefaultProps = {
  foo: string,
};

declare class React2$Element<Config, DP> extends React$Element{
  type: _ReactClass<DP, *, Config, *>;
}


declare function Hoc<Config, DP: DefaultProps, R: React$Element<Config>>(props: {children: R}) : React2$Element<Config, DP>

function TestComponent({foo, bar}: Props){
  return <div>{bar}</div>;
}


function Hoc(props){
  return React.cloneElement(props.children, {foo: 'form2wr'});
}


function Test(){
  return <Hoc children={<TestComponent bar='yo' />}></Hoc>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to this question, but I do have a workaround.

```
type Props = {
  foo: string,
  bar: string,
};

type DefaultProps = {
  foo: string,
};

type WithHOCProps<X> = $Diff<X, DefaultProps>

declare function TestComponent(props: WithHOCProps<Props>) : React$Element;

function TestComponent({foo, bar}: Props){
  return <div>{foo + bar}</div>;
}


function Test(){
  return <TestComponent bar='yo' />;
}
```

Tadahhh, no errors.