# Using Flowtype with react-css-modules decorated components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, react-css-modules

Below is a simple component for showing error messages:

```
// @flow
import styles from 'styles/components/Error';
import React from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';

type Props = {
  message: string
}

const Error = ({ message }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div styleName="error">
      {message}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CSSModules(Error, styles);
```

Note that it requires `message` property. Now if I use this component somewhere:

```
<Error />;
```

Flowtype should warn me that `Error` is missing required property `message` but it does not. If I do not wrap my `Error` component with react-css-modules, Flowtype does work as expected.

I'm thinking that I need to declare a type for Flowtype for it to understand wrapped components but my Google-fu did not yield any results.

What I did found:

- https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1601
- [Flow Type: HOC with cloneElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044801/flow-type-hoc-with-cloneelement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been recently discussed on GitHub. Here's the relevant issue: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2536

In short, the problem is that Flow does not have any type information for the `CSSModules` function, so the return type is inferred as `any`.

In other words:

```
export default Error; // the type of this export is (_: P) => ?React$element<any>
export default CSSModules(Error, styles); // the type of this export is any
```

Long story short, you can provide your own type definition. I'll paste here the one suggested by @gcanti in the original issue:

```
declare module 'react-css-modules' {

  declare type CssOptions = {
    allowMultiple?: boolean,
    errorWhenNotFound?: boolean,
  };

  declare type FunctionComponent<P> = (props: P) => ?React$Element<any>;
  declare type ClassComponent<D, P, S> = Class<React$Component<D, P, S>>;

  declare function exports<D, P, S, C: ClassComponent<D, P, S> | FunctionComponent<P>>(reactClass: C, styles: Object, cssOptions?: CssOptions): C;
}
```

Save the above in `decls/react-css-modules.js` or something similar and then configure your `.flowconfig` like:

```
[libs]
decls/.js
```

This will preserve the type information when wrapping a component into `CSSModules` and allow flow to catch the intended errors.